# Barplot - two bars next to each other and barplots in separate windows

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would  like to use the following data to create a visualization:

```
> dput(data)
structure(c(1264L, 2190L, 2601L, 1441L, 1129L, 2552L, 1820L, 306L, 
            1124L, 298L, 233L, 493L, 2316L, 461L, 294L, 238L, 15L, 89L, 152L, 
            163L, 116L, 60L, 80L, 31L, 27L, 41L, 33L, 58L, 55L, 89L, 7L, 
            7L, 13L, 23L, 54L), .Dim = c(7L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mark1", 
                                                                     "Mark2", "Greg1", "Greg2", "Tom1", "Tom2", "Martin"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                                                                  "5")))
```

I would like to visualize it in a manner somewhat similar to the barplots shown below:

[image: Example]

However, instead of stacking bars on top of each other, I would like to place the barplots to each other. In total there should be 4 windows. A window here refers to a set of two barplots (eg. for Mark1 and Mark2) or a single one in case of Martin.

To make it clearer:

Mark1 and Mark2 - should be in/on the same window

Greg1 and Greg2 - as above

Tom1 and Tom2 - as above

Martin - window consisting of single barplot

Comment: In your data, are the columns "1" through "5" the x-axis of the barchart, with the values in the table the height of the bars?

Comment: @shaxi-liver Just to be clear, do you consider the visualization/window attached in your question as a single barplot?

Comment: @Rahul - exactly. 1 to 5 are the x values and numbers in table are the heights of the bars. Analytical Monk - that was my interpretation. Not a perfect "wording".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` `extract / gather` with the data frame `data` (note that `Martin` is alone and has no `id`, for which a 3rd `fill` color is used):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
as.data.frame(data) %>% 
  mutate(name=rownames(data)) %>% 
  extract(name, c('name','id'),'([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d?)') %>%
  gather(variable, value, -name, -id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill=id)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

**[EDIT]**

```
as.data.frame(data) %>% 
  mutate(name=rownames(data)) %>% 
  extract(name, c('name','id'),'([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d?)', convert=TRUE) %>%
  replace_na(list(id=1)) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -name, -id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill=as.factor(id))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply. How to set up the same color for Martin as well ? I would like to use green in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it using packages from the `tidyverse` universe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)

# d <- your dput data

melt(d) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(name_input=Var1,
         x=Var2,
         value) %>% 
  mutate(name=as.factor(str_extract(string = name_input,
                          pattern = '\\D*')),
         id=str_extract(string = name_input,
                        pattern = '\\d'),
         id=as.factor(ifelse(is.na(id),1,as.numeric(id)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill=id),position='dodge')+
  facet_grid(facets = .~name)
```

[image: ggplot result]

Comment: In my code, I've kept Martin to be a default id=1, but this can be changed if needed.

Comment: How to change the colors for the bars ? I would like to keep them black/grey.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver just add a  `+scale_fill_grey()` to the `ggplot()` code